# Javascript loop to create array of arrays (not loop through array of arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to loop through two arrays of dates, `dateFrom` and `dateTo` to use in a gantt chart plugin. The gantt chart requires `ganttData`. I want to loop through these two arrays simultaneously and create `ganttData` as an array of arrays. Right now, it is looping simultaneously through both arrays but `ganttData` is only the last index of both arrays, which makes sense because I am just reassigning the values each time through the loop.

I tried using `+=` instead of `=` but I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Below is the code that I have so far:

These arrays are correct Ive checked.

I am unfamiliar with JS so any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
var datesFrom = <%= dates_from %>
var datesTo = <%= dates_to %>
//var ganttData = [] if I were to use ganttData += [ below 

output = []
i;

for (i = 0; i < (datesFrom.length - 1); i += 1) {
    ganttData = [{
        id: 1, name: "Feature 1", series: [
            { name: "Planned", start: new Date(datesFrom[i]), end: new Date(datesTo[i]) },
            { name: "Actual", start: new Date(datesFrom[i]), end: new Date(datesTo[i]), color: "#f0f0f0" }
        ]
    }];
};
```

Comment: Are datesFrom and datesTo arrays of the same length?

Comment: Yes they are for now! In the future they may vary but I think I can handle that in the rails code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming datesTo and datesFrom are the same length, you'll want to create an array (ganttData) and push a new object to it for each pair of dates, like so:

```
var ganttData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < datesFrom.length; i++) {
  ganttData.push({
    id: i,
    name: "Feature " + i,
    series: [
      { name: "Planned", start: new Date(datesFrom[i]), end: new Date(datesTo[i]) },
      { name: "Actual", start: new Date(datesFrom[i]), end: new Date(datesTo[i]), color: "#f0f0f0" }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! worked perfectly. my day just got much better!

Answer (score 1):

In general, to build up an array, you'd use this pattern:

```
var ganttData = [];
for (...) {
  ganttData.push({...});
}
```

In JavaScript, as opposed to say Ruby, `array1 + array2` is not defined: it will convert both arguments to strings and concatenate those instead. For array concatenation, you need to use `array1.concat(array2)`, or if you want a destructive method (i.e. to change `array1`), `array1.push.apply(array1, array2)`; but for appending one element, `push` is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the pattern! I will keep this in mind!